# Dynamically update the title in Dash Plotly

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have created this very simplified example in which I would like to dynamically update the title of a chart as a dropdown label changes.
Here's the code:

```
data = {'Stock': ['F',  'NFLX',  'AMZN'], 'Number': [10, 15, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Stock', 'Number'])
stock_options = df['Stock']

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Example Bar Chart'),
    html.Div([
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='dropdown',
            options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in stock_options],
            value='F',

         ),
        html.Div(dcc.Graph(id='graph')),
    ]),
])


@app.callback(
   Output(component_id='graph', component_property='figure'),
   Input(component_id='dropdown', component_property='value')
)
def update_graph(stock):
    msk = df.Stock.isin([stock])
    figure = px.bar(df[msk], x='Stock', y='Number', title=f"{stock} open price")

    return figure


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

So, while keeping the same label in dropdown instead of 'F open price' in the title I would like to get 'Facebook open price'... and so on.
I've tried to solve this with `map` but I couldn't get it working. Can someone point me in the direction on how to resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are the Stock names stored? I.e. how does the program know that it should replace F by Facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, not sure how you want to store the mapping between symbol name and the displayed title in the graph. Here is one solution that works using a dictionary `stock_name_mapping` that contains the symbols als keys and the displayed names as values:

```
import pandas as pd
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

import plotly.express as px

data = {'Stock': ['F',  'NFLX',  'AMZN'], 'Number': [10, 15, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Stock', 'Number'])
stock_options = df['Stock']

stock_name_mapping = {'F': 'Facebook',
                      'NFLX': 'Netflix',
                      'AMZN': 'Amazon'}

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Example Bar Chart'),
    html.Div([
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='dropdown',
            options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in stock_options],
            value='F',

         ),
        html.Div(dcc.Graph(id='graph')),
    ]),
])


@app.callback(
   Output(component_id='graph', component_property='figure'),
   Input(component_id='dropdown', component_property='value')
)
def update_graph(stock):
    msk = df.Stock.isin([stock])
    stock_name = stock_name_mapping[stock]
    figure = px.bar(df[msk], x='Stock', y='Number', title=f"{stock_name} open price")

    return figure


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The solution you offered gives the desired title but I'm getting an empty chart due to values that are set as displayed names. I want to plot 'Number' column values from the example's data frame with the dynamically updated title. I'll try to work on your approach.

Comment: sorry, yes you are right. I updated my answer, it should work now.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again for the effort.